# OpenStack: what's the difference between management network and admin network in Neutron?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm not sure if I understand the purpose of OpenStack Neutron management subnet right.

[OpenStack docs suggest](https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible/train/user/network-arch/example.html) that it is a VLAN that is created to let OpenStack components to talk to each other and also allows me to SSH into the host (physical machine).

I assumed that upon splitting a network interface into VLANs for OpenStack, I abandon the IP address, assigned to that physical interface in untagged l3 network (say, 10.100.70.*), and instead split it into 3 VLANs, and again get an IP address from my provider infrastructure in another provider subnet on this logical interface (say, 10.100.71.*).

But [here is a page](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-install-mirantis-openstack-8-0-with-mellanox-connectx-4-adapters-support--infiniband-network-at-scale-x#jive_content_id_Management) that explains how to install OpenStack with InfiniBand, and it makes use of both management VLAN and PXE/admin interface. So I keep an IP in the untagged PXE network and also create a tagged management VLAN and get IP addresses on both.

Aren't PXE/admin network and management VLAN network redundant here?

Comment: They you are referring to are for Openstack-Ansible. The reference implementation for deploying OpenStack with Ansible uses a management network to 'manage' your cloud using Ansible, but that is not true for all other implementations.

Comment: @BakaKuna Thanks for reply! True, this network config is OpenStack-Ansible-specific and not mandatory in general, however, Mellanox InfiniBand documentation is referring to the same network setup and for some reason they keep both management network and admin/PXE network. Can you see any point in doing so? I thought that if you keep admin/PXE network, the management one is redundant?

Comment: I would imagine that maintaining a seperate PXE network is a security consideration. While you might want to allow all administrators to manage machines using Ansible, you could still confine access to the admin/PXE (and I think IPMI) network to a smaller group dedicated to physical infrastructure.

Comment: @BakaKuna Makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to write down your considerations!